# hibernate transaction rollback is not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

on my dao i have two queries. if the first query is successfully committed then second query should run.but if the first query is committed but second query somehow failed to commit/got some exception then the first query which is committed should also be rolled back. how can i do it?

```
@Repository
public class UpdatePaymentImpl implements UpdatePayment {
     @Autowired
     SessionFactory sessionFactory;
     Session session;
     Transaction trans;

     @Override
     public int updatePayment(@RequestBody UpdateParam updateParam) {
        String totalFee=updateParam.getTotalFee();
        // float amountPaid=Float.toString(updateParam.getAmountPaid());
         String amountPaid=Double.toString(updateParam.getAmountPaid());
         //System.out.println(amountPaid);
         String depositSlioNo=updateParam.getDepositSlipNo();
         String masterId= updateParam.getMasterId();
         String advCode=updateParam.getAdvCode();
         try{
             session=sessionFactory.openSession();
             trans=session.beginTransaction();
             Query query= session.createQuery
            ("update CandidateappearagainstadvtcodeEntity cd set cd.paymentstatus='Completed',
        cd.amountpaid=:depoFee,cd.challanid=:depositSlip where
     cd.studentmasterid=:masterid and cd.advertisementcode=:advCode");
             System.out.println(updateParam.getAdvCode());
             query.setParameter("depoFee",amountPaid);
             query.setParameter("depositSlip",depositSlioNo);
             query.setParameter("masterid",masterId);
             query.setParameter("advCode",advCode);
            int result= query.executeUpdate();
             trans.commit();

             System.out.println("update successful");
             if(result>0){

           String masterId1= updateParam.getMasterId();
           String advCode1=updateParam.getAdvCode();
           Double amountpaid1=updateParam.getAmountPaid();
           session = sessionFactory.openSession();
           trans = session.beginTransaction();
           Query query1 =session.createQuery(" update CandidateappeartoadvtnumberEntity
             cnd set cnd.paymentstatus='Completed', cnd.depositedfee=:depofee where
     cnd.studentmasterid=:masterid 
    and cnd.advertisementcode=:advcode");
     query1.setParameter("depofee",amountpaid1);
     query1.setParameter("masterid",masterId1);
     query1.setParameter("advcode",advCode1);
     int result1 = query1.executeUpdate();
     trans.commit();
     System.out.println("updated");
             }

             return result;
         }catch (Exception e){
             System.out.println("update error " +e);
             trans.rollback();

         return 0;
     }finally {
             session.close();
         }

         }
 }
```

Comment: put them both in one transaction. You cannot rollback a commited transaction.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you creating two different sessions and has separate commit operation.

To reach your goals you have to open one session and one transaction, then execute both queries and only after successful execution do commit.

In that case if any on query execution will fail you won't affect database state. Currently you already commit first query so if your second query will fail the changes from previous query won't be reverted.

[Here is an example](https://www.javatpoint.com/hibernate-transaction-management-example).